# Getting Error 404 after deploying MVC on IIS due to query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I just deployed an MVC app on my IIS and seem to be having issues with any URL with query string.

If I open "http://serverip/app/controller/action", it works fine but if I open "http://serverip/app/controller/action/id", I get error 404.

I don't know what to do. Some links I visited did not help, perhaps, I don't understand the instructions to resolving the issue.

Please help.

Comment: is your action method has an parameter ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Can you share your action codes? And are you using attribute routing?

Comment: Thanks,

Example is: http://192.168.10.23/HumanResource/GetPayGroup/83117817-d0be-4282-a18e-50cd4c47bc89

Comment: That is a simple link from an anchor tag in a table listing records.

@Shyju, yes, it has a parameter:

public ActionResult GetPayGroup(string id) {...}

Comment: what is your IIS and MVC version and Framework ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite often caused by the following missing from the web.config:

```
<system.webserver>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Comment: I have tried that and the error persists.
Do I need to republish my app for this to take effect?

My runtime framework is 4.5 while my IIS is 8

Comment: what is your  IIS and MVC and Framework version  ?both are same?

Comment: I added this and everything works well.
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />

Answer (score 0):

I have experience throwing an exception in Controller will lead to occur this sort of error. returning 404 Not found error to the front end. So make sure that after deploy into  any other environment, if no any configuration or integration issue with API server which will lead to happen exception