# IIS 8.5 returns 404 for {controller}/{action}/{id}

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that is deployed to several servers on IIS 10. All routes work correctly there.

On IIS 8.5, routes that follow {controller}/{action}/{id} return a 404. If the route is changed to {controller}/{action}?id={id}, the correct result is returned with a 200 code.

Is there a setting that must be turned on for IIS 8.5 to correctly map {controller}/{action}/{id} to an MVC controller?

My route config:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Relevant sections of web config:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxUrlLength="99999" maxQueryStringLength="99999" />
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
       <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" /> 
       <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" /> 
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

I've tried the suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075785/getting-error-404-after-deploying-mvc-on-iis-due-to-query-string) but they did not fix the 404s.

Comment: What is the url you are trying to access ?

Comment: https://example.com:8080/controller/action/id. It's an internal B2B site so not something you'd be able to test against.

Comment: is that the actual url you are trying to use ? You have a controller called `controllerController` and an action method called `action(int id)` ?

Comment: No. The controller is named something else and so is the action. The parameter is named id.

Comment: That is exactly what i asked in my first comment! What url are you trying ? and what is your action method signature looks like ?

Comment: example.com:8080/Room/RecentPerformances/8 for example. example.com:8080/RoomClientEvents/EventImage/135266 for another.  Does it make a difference?

Comment: Do you have an action method called `RecentPerformances` which has an int parameter named `id` ?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned in my post, this site and these actions in particular work at multiple other instances of the same MVC site running on IIS 10/Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Can you edit and include your web.config looks like something is missing there. I am thinking something is not enabled or installed on this iis 8 machine. URLRouting module from system.web ? Like from the post your mentioned.

Comment: Edited to include web.config. Any other sections you want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something seemed to have gotten borked in IIS for just that site. Deleting and redeploying the site fixed the problem